# Although my rvm points to 2.1.6, i still get this error "Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.6"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I get the above error when i run rake db:create.
I have rvm installed and it's already set to 2.1.6
Bundle install runs perfectly without any error, with following output :

Using rake 11.3.0

Using i18n 0.7.0

Using json 1.8.3

Using minitest 5.10.1

Using thread_safe 0.3.5

Using builder 3.2.2

Using erubis 2.7.0

Using rack 1.5.5

Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521

Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214

Using babel-source 5.8.35

Using execjs 2.7.0

Using byebug 9.0.5

Using coderay 1.1.1

Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0

Using thor 0.19.4

Using connection_pool 2.2.0

Using diff-lcs 1.2.5

Using multipart-post 2.0.0

Using hike 1.2.3

Using simple_oauth 0.2.0

Using multi_json 1.12.1

Using kgio 2.10.0

Using libv8 3.16.14.15

Using method_source 0.8.2

Using pg 0.19.0

Using slop 3.6.0

Using bundler 1.13.6

Using tilt 1.4.1

Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5

Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5

Using raindrops 0.17.0

Using ref 2.0.0

Using rspec-support 3.4.1

Using sass 3.2.19

Using rdoc 4.2.2

Using tzinfo 1.2.2

Using rack-test 0.6.3

Using mime-types 3.1

Using babel-transpiler 0.7.0

Using uglifier 3.0.0

Using coffee-script 2.4.1

Using faraday 0.9.2

Using pry 0.10.4

Using sprockets 2.12.4

Using rails_12factor 0.0.3

Using unicorn 5.2.0

Using therubyracer 0.12.2

Using rspec-core 3.4.4

Using rspec-expectations 3.4.0

Using rspec-mocks 3.4.1

Using sdoc 0.4.1

Using activesupport 4.1.6

Using mail 2.6.4

Using faraday_middleware 0.10.0

Using actionview 4.1.6

Using activemodel 4.1.6

Using jbuilder 1.5.3

Using ims-lti 2.0.0.beta.41

Using actionpack 4.1.6

Using activerecord 4.1.6

Using actionmailer 4.1.6

Using railties 4.1.6

Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3

Using coffee-rails 4.0.1

Using jquery-rails 3.1.4

Using lodash-rails 3.7.0

Using rspec-rails 3.4.2

Using rails 4.1.6

Using sass-rails 4.0.5

Using turbolinks 2.5.3

Using rails_lti2_provider 0.0.1 from https://github.com/rivernate/rails_lti2_provider.git (at 42ea6ba@42ea6ba)

Using react-rails 1.5.0

Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 73 gems now installed.

Comment: i have tried other links, but they are of no help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the above solutions, but none of them worked for me. I reinstalled rvm , and it did the trick